# Grub menu (while booting) shows its GRUB2 though the version is 0.97

Tags: boot, grub2

I had installed on my hard disk Ubuntu 12.10 (I think its GRUB version was 0.97). Then I upgraded to 13.04. When now I run `grub-install -v`, it shows its GRUB 2.00

I later faced issue with Ubuntu13.04 that I wasn't able to boot. So using live Ubuntu 12.10 CD, I reinstalled my GRUB. But then when the same command was run (`grub-install -v`), It showed its GRUB 0.97

That means the live CD of Ubuntu 12.10 had GRUB 0.97. So, I used to work with this set up. [ Now 1 serious point arises. Does Ubuntu 12.10 has GRUB version 0.97? Because [Ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) says that since Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala), its GRUB 2 ]

But what I noticed that thought the command outputs GRUB version 0.97, when I boot the system  the boot menu shows GRUB 2.0 (written at the top as heading). Though its clear that my GRUB is 0.97 (as confirmed by the command run in terminal), so that's what I was thinking why the GRUB menu ( while booting ) shows the wrong version.

What I think is that as my original O.S. (13.04) had GRUB 2.0, so due to reinstalling GRUB from Ubuntu12.10 (which has GRUB version 0.97), the boot-loader changed from GRUB 2.0 to GRUB version 0.97 but the heading remained unchanged.

Please focus some light on this.

I would like to add that I followed Ubuntu site and upgraded my GRUB from 0.97 to GRUB 2.0. Now I get the below output:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ grub-install -v
grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-13ubuntu3
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

> EDIT

I have rechecked and found that I as ran `sudo apt-get install grub` with an intent to run grub command, I got grub legacy without my knowledge. Yesterday I upgraded my GRUB from legacy to GRUB 2. To test my question that I asked, just now I installed boot-loader from Ubuntu 12.10 live CD. I checked via command line in the live CD the version of GRUB & it showed `GNU GRUB version 2.00-7ubuntu11`. Then I removed the live CD and rebooted. In the GRUB menu, it showed the same GRUB version as above i.e. `GNU GRUB version 2.00-7ubuntu11`. But after logging, via command line it showed `grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-13ubuntu3`. This is what the command line had output yesterday i.e. before I reinstalled GRUB today from live CD. Why this diff.?

Comment: If you install grub you get grub legacy (last version 0.97). If you install grub-pc then you get grub2 that with Ubuntu 9.10 started with 1.97 and with 13.10 grub2's version is 2.00.

Comment: @oldfred O.K. that's clear, thanks. But can you please explain the difference that I asked in my edited Q. Why at the time of booting its `GNU GRUB version 2.00-7ubuntu11` and command line outputs as `grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-13ubuntu3`. I repeat the former version corresponds to the live CD of Ubuntu 12.10 and the latter one corresponds to the latest version (which I got after upgrading my GRUB). Both should match, isn't it?

Comment: I would think it should match if you only have one install. I have multiple installs so the version I boot with may not be the version in the install I boot into.

Answer (score 2):

Both grub & grub2 use the same grub install command, but it depends on which package you have installed. If you uninstalled grub-pc which is grub2 and installed grub you then have the old grub legacy.

From your chroot.

uninstall both grub legacy & grub2 reinstall grub2 and to sda

```
apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
mkdir /boot/grub
apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

Comment: Yes that's what had happened. I have edited my Q. Please have a look\

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as you can read here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2, Grub (being version 0.97 and other 0.xx versions) has been replaced by it successor Grub 2 (showing up as version 1.97 and up) since Ubuntu 9.10. So your Ubuntu 12.10 installation very probably already had Grub 2 installed. I also remember my 12.04 installation saying it had Grub 2 (more specifically 1.99 I think but I'm not sure) installed.

I do not know why the command line on your 12.10 CD is stating that it is Grub 0.97, but I am pretty sure it is actually already Grub 2. Perhaps you stumbled on bug in that 12.10 version or due to legacy reasons Grub 0.97 is still present. In the latter case I do not know why it would have installed Grub 0.97 instead of Grub 2 on your system.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I had this point (that you raised) in my mind while posting my Q but missed. So, now I have edited my Q. One more thing I would like to clarify that when I don't remember what GRUB version it was showing when I had made a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 on my hard disk. But later I concluded that it was 0.97 only when I reinstalled boot-loader on Ubuntu 13.04 (12.10 was upgraded to 13.04)